# How handle priority for subdirectories in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I am having a problem with a Makefile.am file (automake file).

Here an extract of the Makefile.am in the root directory:

```
SUBDIRS = $(lib_dir) \
          src
```

The problem is that make tries to build src before the lib_dir.

Is there a way to define priority for the subdirectories builds?

EDIT: the error was mine... I missnamed lib_dir variable. Delete this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be built in order they are mentioned in SUBDIRS. So, just try to swap them.